# How to last clicked navigation menu and active navigation menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question, i use master page, and I need to session for navigation menu, (last clicked navigation menu and add class: 'active' navigation menu) and active when page loads

How can i do ?

Code:

```
<ul class="x-navigation" id="menuactive">
<li class="**active**">
    <a href="#">Title 1</a>
</li>   
<li>
    <a href="#">Title 2</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"> Title 2_1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Title 2_2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li></ul>
```

...

Thank you for helping me!!!

Answer (score 0):

Adding class Removing Class just like you said

```js
$('ul > li > a').click(function() {
  $('ul > li > a').removeClass('addclass');
  $(this).addClass('addclass');
});
```

```css
.addclass {
  background-color: #ff5722;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="x-navigation" id="menuactive">
  <li class="**active**">
    <a href="#">Title 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Title 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class='addclass'> Title 2_1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Title 2_2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. But I want to div active when page loads. I use javascript sessionStorage, cookie, but failed :(

Comment: @ChimDiTrú You want it as selected when page load? its easy just add your class at start then you can click